# Spring MVC - unable to @Autowire messageSource

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

I've a custom exception class that need to read some error messages from properties files. But it seems like it keep on getting null. I've even tried adding @Component but still does not work

```
@Component
public class FormValidationFailExceptionHolder {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    ...
    public void someMethod(){
        ....
        String message = messageSource.getMessage(errorid, msgargs, Locale.ENGLISH);
        ....
    }
}
```

Here is my spring config

```
....
<context:component-scan base-package="simptex.my" />
....
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="false" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:mgmtlabels</value>
            <value>classpath:error</value>
            <value>classpath:PWMResources</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

I've even tried to declare the bean explicitly in the spring config xml but still returning null

```
<bean id="formValidationFailException" class="simptex.my.core.exception.FormValidationFailException">
    <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>
```

Here is how I call FormValidationFailException

```
public class Foo{
    private HttpSession session;
    ....
    public void fooMethod()  {
        session.setAttribute(CommonSessionKeys.FORM_VALIDATION_EXECEPTION_HOLDER, new FormValidationFailExceptionHolder("roledd", "E0001"));
    }
}

@Controller
public class FooController  {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/xxxx")
    public void fooMethodxxx() {
        Foo foo = new Foo(session);
        foo.fooMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you really want to achieve is a custom form validator.

```
@Component
public class CustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz == FormBean.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        FormBean bean = (FormBean) target;

        if ( StringUtils.isEmpty( bean.getField() ) ) {
            errors.rejectValue("field", "field.empty");
        }

    }
}
```

The "field.empty" is a key in your properties file.

```
field.empty=Field mustn't be empty
```

Now in your controller you need to add:

```
@Autowired
private CustomValidator customValidator; 

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    if (binder.getTarget() instanceof FormBean) {
        binder.setValidator(customValidator);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/xxxx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String fooMethodxxx(@ModelAttribute("bean") @Validated FormBean bean, BindingResult result) {
        if ( result.hasErrors() ) {
            prepareModel(model);
            return "form.view";
        }
        return "other.view"
    }
```

When you post the form it will be validated. To show user the validation message in jsp you need to add:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<f:errors cssClass="error" path="field"></f:errors>
<f:input path="field" type="text"/>
```

I think this is the proper way of handling custom validator.

Comment: thanks.. I ended up using the "classic" way of getting the labels. having a that uses `ResourceBundleMessageSource`

Comment: vincent - Could you please share how you solved this issue. I can't autowire MessageSource (ResourceBundleMessageSource) at all in a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint